# How do I to test the wrappers of AWS Lambda handlers in Go?

Tags: go, testing, aws-lambda

I have created some functions that act as "middleware" on a Lambda handler. I wanted to separate the logic of what the handler is doing from whether or not the caller has permission to do the thing.

I have a situation where a caller may need additional authentication depending on the request they made. I have 2 "middleware" that accomplish this.

The first determines if the request requires additional authentication, and if so, forwards to the second. If not, executes the handler.

The second does the additional authentication.

middleware.go

```
package middleware

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
)

type middleware func(context.Context, events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error)

func NeedsAdditionalAuth(next middleware) middleware {
    return func(ctx context.Context, proxyRequest events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
        if proxyRequest.QueryStringParameters["status"] == "sensitive" { //An example. This is whatever the request has that would require additional auth.
            return AdditionalAuth(next)(ctx, proxyRequest)
        }
        return next(ctx, proxyRequest)
    }
}

func AdditionalAuth(next middleware) middleware {
    return func(ctx context.Context, proxyRequest events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
        authenticated := doAdditionalAuth()

        if !authenticated {
            return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
                StatusCode: http.StatusForbidden,
            }, nil
        }
        
        return next(ctx, proxyRequest)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "middleware"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: 200,
        Body:       "(☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞ Middleware approved Hello World!",
    }, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(
        middleware.NeedsAdditionalAuth(
            Handler,
        ),
    )
}
```

And now for my question: How would I test the individual functionality of these "middleware" functions?

Specifically if I sent in a request that met the requirements for additional auth:

```
proxyRequest := &events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{
    QueryStringParameters: map[string]string{
        "status":  "sensitive",
    },
}
```

How do I write a test that confirms: "middleware.AdditionalAuth() was called 1 time with the expected arguments"